# How to Map a List of Java Entity to Multiple MongoDB Collections in Spring Data?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Currently, we're looking for a solution to save the List of User entity into multiple MongoDB collections at the same time (i.e. db_users and on db_users_legacy). Both collections are in the same database.

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282952/how-to-map-a-java-entity-to-multiple-mongodb-collections-in-spring-data). In this link they are saving single User entity into two different collections. But , I want to insert list of User entity into two different collections. I tried to insert using for loop. But it is taking time to iterate entire list and save object one by one.

```
 @Override
    public void saveUser(List<User> userList) {
     for(User user: userList) {
        mongoTemplate.save(user, "db_users");
        mongoTemplate.save(user, "db_users_legacy");
       }
    }
```

Is there any way to insert List of User entity into two different collections at one shot without using any for loop ?

Comment: `MongoTemplate` has an `insert` method that takes a collection of objects to save, e.g.:`mongoTemplate.insert(userList, "db_users")`. Also, there is an `insertAll` method which can save to different collections based upon the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot @prasad_. Will try your suggestion.