# How to mapping an entity to multiple mongodb collection in Spring Data MongoDB with JPA without use MongoTempalte directly?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using `org.mongodb:bson:4.1.2` with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.4.7`.

My entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fire_alert")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Document(collection = "alert_<dynamic>")
@Data
public class AlertPO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "owner_id")
    private Long ownerId;

    @Column(name = "alert_type")
    private Long alertType;
}
```

Cause there will be millions of alerts, so I need to save records into different mongodb collections based on `AlertPO.alertType`.

After digging into `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity`, I found the field `collection` of annotation `@Document` support `SpEL` expression. This kind of expressions will be evaluated in `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity#getCollection` and  it is obviously that current entity won't be added into the `EvaluationContext`.

According to this question:

[How to Map a Java Entity to Multiple MongoDB Collections in Spring Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282952/how-to-map-a-java-entity-to-multiple-mongodb-collections-in-spring-data)

We can overwrite repositories to use `MongoTemplate` to persistent data into proper collection programmatically. But we're going to using JPA and we do not want to using `MongoTemplate` directly. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the `SpEL` expression's `EvaluationContext` contains no instances of `AlertPO`, but we can make it possible through `ThreadLocal` instances registered in `BeanFactory`.

Such as:

```
@Component(value = "collection")
public class CollectionHolder {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Stack<String>> COLLECTION = ThreadLocal.withInitial(Stack::new);

    public void push(Alert alert) {
        COLLECTION.get().push(typeToCollection(alert.getAlertType()));
    }

    public void push(Long type) {
        COLLECTION.get().push(typeToCollection(type));
    }

    public String top() {
        return COLLECTION.get().peek();
    }

    public void pop() {
        COLLECTION.get().pop();
    }
}
```

Now we can push collection name:

```
@Service
public class MongoAlertStorage implements IAlertStorage {
    @Autowired
    private CollectionHolder holder;
    @Autowired
    private AlertRepository alertRepository;
    @Autowired
    private Converters converters;

    @Override
    public Alert save(Alert alert) throws Exception {
        try {
            holder.push(alert);
            return converters.of(alertRepository.save(converters.of(alert)));
        } finally {
            holder.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

It is time to specify dynamic collection in expression:

```
@Document(collection = "alert_#{@collection.top()}")
public class AlertPO implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

Now, you can debug at `org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression#getValue(org.springframework.expression.EvaluationContext)` to check the value evaluated, it should be what you want.